# How can I get the value in android sugar, I'm only getting the object reference

Tags: android, sugarorm

I'm using for first time sugar and all seems that work fine. I can save the data and seems that I'm getting the data when I try to do a find. My problem is that I'm getting the object and not the value that I have store and I'm not really sure why, because I'm doing the same that I can see in the official documentation

This is that I'm doing to get the data:

```
    Select name= Select.from(MyClass.class).where(Condition.prop("name").lt("Bob"));

    String data = name.toString();

    Log.e("aaaaa", data.toString());
```

This is that I'm gettin in the log:

```
com.orm.query.Select@3ce7ff7b
```

Comment: seems like you have a result array or iterator in the `Select` object - this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

With that Select statement, you are querying for the MyClass object by name, and that returns you a Select object.

To get the name from it you should fetch results from the Select (here I do it with `.first()`) and put that in a MyClass object. Then you can get the name from that.

```
MyClass myClass = Select.from(MyClass.class)
                      .where(Condition.prop("name").lt("Bob"))
                      .first();

String name = myClass.getName();
```

provided your MyClass has a method `getName()`

Comment: I'm trying to do this, but I'm getting a Error when try to build the project:(194, 131) error: incompatible types
required: MyClass
found:    SugarRecord

Answer (score 0):

> I'm doing the same that I can see in the official documentation

I don't thnk you are.

In the documentation [here](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/query.html), it shows this piece of code:

```
Select.from(TestRecord.class)
.where(Condition.prop("test").eq("satya"),
Condition.prop("prop").eq(2))
.list();
```

When you compare it with your code, you see that you missed the call to `list`.

If you don't call `list`, the `where` method will return a `Select` object. And that's all you get.

`list` will return all of the results that the query has found. So the correct way to do this would be:

```
List<MyClass> results = 
    Select.from(MyClass.class).
    where(Condition.prop("name").
    lt("Bob")).list();

for (MyClass obj: results) {
    Log.i("aaaa", obj.toString());
    // or you can write
    // Log.i("aaaa", obj.name);
}
```

The above would print all the results. If you only need the first result, you can call `results.get(0)`.